# Is it reasonable to change the input shape for a trained convolutional neural network

Tags: input, keras, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I've seen a number of super-resolution networks that seem to imply that it's fine to train a network on inputs of (x,y,d) but then pass in images of arbitrary sizes into a model for prediction, that in Keras for example is specified with the placeholder values (None,None,3) and will accept any size.

for example https://github.com/krasserm/super-resolution is trained on inputs of 24x24x3 but accepts arbitrary sized images for resize, the demo code using 124x118x3.

Is this a sane practice? Does the network when given a larger input simply slide a window over it applying the same weights as it learnt on the smaller size image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct. Convolutional layers learn to distinguish features at the scale of their kernel, not at the scale of the image as a whole. A layer with a 3x3 kernel will learn to identify a feature up to 3x3 pixels large and will be able to identify that feature in an image whether the image is itself 3x3, 100x100, or 1080x1920.

Comment: The detail that the kernel size is all the convolutional layer 'sees' is a useful elucidation, thanks.

Comment: This is sort of arguable. If the net was trained for recognizing images in many scales, it will be able to handle many image sizes. (Although it's true that internally there will probably be separate dedicated kernels to each scale)

Answer (score 1):

There will be absolutely no problem with the convolutions, they will work exactly as they are expected to, with the same weights, same kernel size, etc. etc.

The only possible problem is: the model may not have learned the new scale of your images (because it has never seen this scale before) and may give you poor results.

On the other hand, the model could be trained with many sizes/scales, becoming more robust to variation.

---

There will be a problem with `Flatten`, `Reshape`, etc.
Only `GlobalMaxPooling2D` and `GlobalAveragePooling2D` will support different sizes.